# How to instamojo integrated in android

Tags: android, instamojo

Im new for android, I want to add payment option in my app. So, I used instamojo. Im include instamojo library in gradle file. But gradle file throw error.

Error:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: in.juspay:godel:0.6.11.0823
```

My gradle file:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.7'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.instamojo:android-sdk:1.2.4'
}
```

If i run the instamojo sdk in separate application means working perfectly.If i integrate with my app means getting above gradle error.

Please, anyone help to resolve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't Google provide its own way of in-app-payments? I guess you might have less trouble with them.

Comment: Hey see this link https://docs.instamojo.com/page/android-sdk#section-include-sdk. I think you have not added the repository of maven in you application gradle file.

Comment: @SagarGangawane Now, I get this error  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: @Abu show the errors.See the logs then let me know the errors.

Comment: @SagarGangawane Log shows like this, Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Answer (score 1):

> Error:Failed to resolve: in.juspay:godel:0.6.11.0823

[From here](https://www.juspay.in/docs/juspay-safe/android/sdk/index.html) or [here](https://docs.instamojo.com/page/android-sdk)

You should have an `allprojects` block, that contains some lines like this

```
// Add to build.gradle

repositories {
  jcenter()  // <-- should already be there

  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/"
  }
}
```

---

And in `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  // compile 'in.juspay:godel:0.6.12.0823' // maybe need this?
  compile 'com.instamojo:android-sdk:1.2.4'

  // your other dependencies
  ...
  ...
}
```

---

Also, this line needs not to be there. `compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` [It should be in the `classpath` of the `buildscript` `dependencies` block.](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

And `'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` should use `23.2.0` to match the other Android support versions.

---

Regarding "Manifest merger failed", you [can search to find something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=manifest+merger+failed), and start with removing this line, because it's redundant with the other dependencies.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

// Add to build.gradle

```
repositories {
  jcenter()  // <-- should already be there

  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/"
  }
}
```

then add this in your manifest file

```
<meta-data android:name="instamojo.orderauth.url"
            android:value="ur website name/access_token.php"
            />
```